My github repo converted itself to LFS even when no large files are present in folder? How do I revert this?
I use Github desktop to backup my Unity project. I have been using it for years but last night after making changes to my project I tried to commit changes and push them to main but github desktop would hand on pushing to origin and would not progress.
After searching for it online I came across this post: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/14331#issuecomment-1308575748
I wrote the commands that were suggested but even then github desktop did not work.
Thinking this was a problem with github desktop I then used git bash and used the command git push to push my commits.
This is what I got in bash:
$ git push
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (2845/2845), 799 MB | 1.8 MB/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 5776, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5776/5776), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3163/3163), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3164/3164), 431.66 KiB | 16.60 MiB/s, done.
Total 3164 (delta 278), reused 2885 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (278/278), completed with 278 local objects.

Why did this upload as LFS? I do not have a single file over 20MB in my project? Also after this I got an email that I have used about 80% of my LFS quota?
Why did it upload as LFS and how do I revert this?
Also, I would like to add that due to an different error I got some time back the solution I came across was to add the following Unity .gitattributes file.
This was some time back and the LFS problem did not appear then, but I imagine clearing the cache caused this LFS problem to show up.
# Define macros (only works in top-level gitattributes files)
[attr]lfs               filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
[attr]unity-json        eol=lf linguist-language=json
[attr]unity-yaml        merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf linguist-language=yaml

# Optionally collapse Unity-generated files on GitHub diffs
# [attr]unity-yaml        merge=unityyamlmerge text linguist-language=yaml linguist-generated

# Unity source files
*.cginc                 text
*.compute               text linguist-language=hlsl
*.cs                    text diff=csharp
*.hlsl                  text linguist-language=hlsl
*.raytrace              text linguist-language=hlsl
*.shader                text

# Unity JSON files
*.asmdef                unity-json
*.asmref                unity-json
*.index                 unity-json
*.inputactions          unity-json
*.shadergraph           unity-json
*.shadersubgraph        unity-json

# Unity UI Toolkit files
*.tss                   text diff=css linguist-language=css
*.uss                   text diff=css linguist-language=css
*.uxml                  text linguist-language=xml linguist-detectable

# Unity YAML
*.anim                  unity-yaml
*.asset                 unity-yaml
*.brush                 unity-yaml
*.controller            unity-yaml
*.flare                 unity-yaml
*.fontsettings          unity-yaml
*.giparams              unity-yaml
*.guiskin               unity-yaml
*.lighting              unity-yaml
*.mask                  unity-yaml
*.mat                   unity-yaml
*.meta                  unity-yaml
*.mixer                 unity-yaml
*.overrideController    unity-yaml
*.playable              unity-yaml
*.prefab                unity-yaml
*.preset                unity-yaml
*.renderTexture         unity-yaml
*.scenetemplate         unity-yaml
*.shadervariants        unity-yaml
*.signal                unity-yaml
*.spriteatlas           unity-yaml
*.spriteatlasv2         unity-yaml
*.terrainlayer          unity-yaml
*.unity                 unity-yaml

# "physic" for 3D but "physics" for 2D
*.physicMaterial        unity-yaml
*.physicsMaterial2D     unity-yaml

# Exclude third-party plugins from GitHub stats
Assets/Plugins/**       linguist-vendored

# Unity LFS
*.cubemap               lfs
*.unitypackage          lfs

# 3D models
*.3dm                   lfs
*.3ds                   lfs
*.blend                 lfs
*.c4d                   lfs
*.collada               lfs
*.dae                   lfs
*.dxf                   lfs
*.FBX                   lfs
*.fbx                   lfs
*.jas                   lfs
*.lws                   lfs
*.lxo                   lfs
*.ma                    lfs
*.max                   lfs
*.mb                    lfs
*.obj                   lfs
*.ply                   lfs
*.skp                   lfs
*.stl                   lfs
*.ztl                   lfs

# Audio
*.aif                   lfs
*.aiff                  lfs
*.it                    lfs
*.mod                   lfs
*.mp3                   lfs
*.ogg                   lfs
*.s3m                   lfs
*.wav                   lfs
*.xm                    lfs

# Video
*.asf                   lfs
*.avi                   lfs
*.flv                   lfs
*.mov                   lfs
*.mp4                   lfs
*.mpeg                  lfs
*.mpg                   lfs
*.ogv                   lfs
*.wmv                   lfs

# Images
*.bmp                   lfs
*.exr                   lfs
*.gif                   lfs
*.hdr                   lfs
*.iff                   lfs
*.jpeg                  lfs
*.jpg                   lfs
*.pict                  lfs
*.png                   lfs
*.psd                   lfs
*.tga                   lfs
*.tif                   lfs
*.tiff                  lfs
*.webp                  lfs

# Compressed Archive
*.7z                    lfs
*.bz2                   lfs
*.gz                    lfs
*.rar                   lfs
*.tar                   lfs
*.zip                   lfs

# Compiled Dynamic Library
*.dll                   lfs
*.pdb                   lfs
*.so                    lfs

# Fonts
*.otf                   lfs
*.ttf                   lfs

# Executable/Installer
*.apk                   lfs
*.exe                   lfs

# Documents
*.pdf                   lfs

# ETC
*.a                     lfs
*.reason                lfs
*.rns                   lfs

# Spine export file for Unity
*.skel.bytes            lfs

I feel the .gitattributes tagging all these file types to LFS is the cause of this.
How do I revert this please? I am only using small files (no greater than 20MB)
Thanks

Ref: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3026
git lfs uninstall

git lfs ls-files — view lfs files
git rm -r --cached .

git add * 
git commit -m "restore files from lfs"


remove lfs .gitattribute entries
Prune LFS Objects -
git lfs prune
git lfs cache --clear

git push origin --force



So I believe I managed to resolve this.
I first updated my .gitattributes and removed all lfs tags and then commit that.
Then I cleared cache of my local rep using git rm -r --cached . to undo the lfs changes that i made.
Then commit and did a git push this time the files were uploaded as regular git objects.
Git hub desktop is still not working and getting stuck on push.. So I just downloaded SourceTree and used that to push and its working without any problems.
